# How to access the Administrator Command Prompt in Windows 8?

Tags: command-line, windows-8

When I access the **Run** dialog in Windows 8 and type `cmd`, it opens a command prompt but it doesn't have administrative privileges.

Looking for `cmd` at the default start screen does show a command prompt shortcut but it is not admin either.

**Is there a way of opening an admin command prompt or it is not possible anymore?**

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Yes, it is possible and there are several ways of doing it:

1. This one is my favorite because it's quite fast, press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to bring the power user menu up and then press <kbd>A</kbd>; it opens right away.
2. Right click in the bottom left corner of the screen to open that menu too, and then click on "Command Prompt (Admin)".

   [image: Menu]
3. Launching it from the start screen is also possible, and there are 2 ways that I know of:

   3.1. Holding down <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> before clicking it (or any other program for the matter) will open it with admin privileges (thanks to ernie for the info).

   3.2. Holding down <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> alone or right clicking the shortcut will show a bottom menu with options, one of which is "Run as administrator":

   [image: Graphically]

Anyway as Misha says you should really consider if you need an administrator terminal.

Comment: I need it to delete some leftover folders and files from the upgrade, I can't in the regular explorer.

Comment: @Charles: just run it as administrator?

Comment: Another option is to hold ctrl while pressing enter when launching the Command Prompt (or any application)

Comment: @xandy yes, ctrl-shift - sorry about the confusion.

Comment: Thanks, Win+X+A surely will become my favorite method, but for I wonder: Is there a way to run anyhing as administrator in "Run" command promt? For example, Win+R opens the Run window, and we usually type `cmd`. What can be done similarly but to run cmd as admin? THANKS!

Answer (score 5):

It is also in the <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> power user menu

A cursory Google search yields rather [exhuastive results](http://www.softwareok.com/?seite=faq-Windows-8&faq=7). I would strongly encourage you to proceed with caution as you can do irreversable damage to your system.

Comment: I need it to delete some leftover folders and files from the upgrade, I can't in the regular explorer.

Comment: @Charles Formost, never, never do an upgrade install. It doesn't work. My entire hope of completing the Windows 8 Challange is fueled by people who do upgrade installs. This sounds like an ownership issue that can be addrssed by changing the ownership of the folders: which can be done in the explorer.

Comment: I have an upgrade license, that's why I did upgrade, but there were things left behind or something.

Comment: @Charles, I would strongly encourage you to do a clean install. This is possibel from an upgrade installation. I would personally do a clean install using the upgrade media from a running copy of Windows 8.

Answer (score 4):

You can pin the cmd to your taskbar and do the following:

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can go to all apps, find command prompt, right click, and then run as administrator.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If you are upgrading or have bought a new computer with **Windows 8.1** the following ways maybe helpful:

**A.** *Opening Command Prompt as administrator from Start screen.*

1. When you are in the Start screen, type **Command Prompt** to see Command Prompt in the search result.
2. Do a **right-click** on the Command Prompt entry and then click **Run as administrator** option to open elevated Command Prompt.

[image]

**B.** *Switch To Start Screen.* (Use this method if you prefer to open admin Command Prompt from desktop.)

The power user menu or the **Win+X** menu that appears when you right-click on the Start button on the Windows 8.1 taskbar shows Windows PowerShell and Windows PowerShell (admin) options with default settings.

If you prefer to use Command Prompt over PowerShell, you can configure Windows 8.1 to display Command Prompt and Command Prompt (admin) options in the power user menu by following given below steps:

- Right-click on the empty space of taskbar and then click **Properties** to open Taskbar and Navigation Properties dialog.

[image]

- Switch to the **Navigation** tab and check the option titled Replace **Command Prompt with Windows PowerShell in the menu when I right-click the lower-left corner of press Windows key + X** to replace Windows PowerShell option in the power user menu with Command Prompt.

[image]

- From now on, you can simply **right-click** on the Start button, click **Command Prompt (admin)** and then click on the Yes button when you see the UAC prompt to run Command Prompt as administrator.

[image]

Additional ways to access administrator command prompt in Windows 8.1 including the methods described above can be found [here](http://www.intowindows.com/how-to-open-command-prompt-as-administrator-in-windows-8-1/).

Answer (score 2):

Another way is to go to Start Screen, search for CMD and then press SHIFT + CTRL + ENTER.
This will elevate the cmd prompt.

This works for opening any application as administrator by the way.