# How to remove pre-installed Flash Player in Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, flash, uninstall, flash-player

Windows 8 comes with Flash Player pre-installed. How do I remove it? It does not appear in "Programs and Features".

Comment: why you want to do that?

Comment: Try the Flash Player uninstaller from http://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/kb/uninstall-flash-player-windows.html

Comment: This tools uninstall ONLY flash player for Firefox, chrome, Opera , Safari and ....

Comment: @Kaveh - Adobe software is a collection of insecure junk. I don't allow Adobe products on my network. Its December, 2016. Adobe's garbage is still catching security vulnerabilities, and Microsoft still does not provide a way to remove the junk. Why do users have to suffer security bugs like [KB 3209498](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3209498) when they don't want the sh**t in the first place. It should be illegal for Microsoft to claim any of their OSes are secure when their image ships with the Adobe junk.

Answer (score 4):

**Officially this is not supported**.

***Make a complete Windows Image (recImgexe) first*** and download the tool [win6x_registry_tweak](http://www.msfn.org/board/topic/152688-win6x-registry-tweak/). Now open [a cmd prompt with admin rights](https://superuser.com/questions/497252/how-to-access-the-administrator-command-prompt-in-windows-8), in the folder where you stored the Exe, and run this command

```
install_wim_tweak.exe /o /c Adobe-Flash-For-Windows-Package /r
```

This kills the Flash package. After a reboot it is gone.

Comment: Can I assume then there is no "out of the box" way of just removing it?

Comment: @Ramhound if you have no idea, don't reply. This works fine in Windows 8. I've used it to kill Flash and Defender. And yes, Dave MSFT doesn't include an official way, that's why I wrote it is unsupported ;) To customize your Windows, MSFT wants you to buy "Windows Embedded".

Comment: I check the latest files, this month they did it. All former updates where still 11.3.