# Restore Windows 8.1 native flash player that I deleted

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, flash-player

By following this thread
[How to remove pre-installed Flash Player in Windows 8?](https://superuser.com/questions/559149/how-to-remove-pre-installed-flash-player-in-windows-8)
I managed to delete the flash player but one of my games called Soldier front 2 uses flash player IE Active X for launcher and game. I tried installing from Adobe using Internet Explorer version Windows 7 but it says flash player is already installed bla bla.
    So, my question is how do I undo the process and get back the native IE Active X flash player windows 8.1?

I found a solution at the last line of this thread but it's too difficult
http://www.msfn.org/board/topic/152688-win6x-registry-tweak/page-3

It's at the last line; he says

> You need to first extract the adobe flash .cab from a .wim that still
>   has it.
>
> What's that ?  You don't know how to extract packages from
>   a .wim, try [Bubbles Super Nasty SFX Extractor Tool](http://forums.mydigitallife.info/threads/48325-VBScript-Aunty-Mel-s-Cheap-And-Nasty-SxS-Package-Extractor-%28Updated-2013-09-30%29/page2?p=848055&viewfull=1#post848055).  (written by
>   myself and bubbles)  The trick apparently is to do all this under the
>   TrustedInstaller account so that things extract properly (don't worry,
>   instructions included).  It helps you create a package that can be
>   re-inserted via DISM add-package command (or something similarly
>   easy).

So any ideas please help me. I don't wanna re-install Windows just for it :(

Comment: What is confusing about that?  I was able to follow the directions without a problem

Comment: I extracted the .cab file.  I don't actually have to "restore" the player since it already works.

Comment: Please i understand nothing help me get my flash player back its completely gone -_-

Comment: I ask specifically what step is confusing about the tutorial?  The first step have you repaired the `Windows Compontent Store` by running the dism tool?

Comment: My windows is Fine i just want the IE based built in flash player back for windows 8.1 which i deleted using the win6X.

Comment: @bijay135 You deleted Flash Player for Internet Explorer?  Just reinstall it at adobe.com/flashplayer

Comment: I already said i specially need the flash player for IE based its only available for windows 7 sill when i install it says u already have a built in flash player but its deleted -_-

Comment: My a suggestion to run the DISM command is the first step in creating the .wim file you need.  Additionally your component store isn't fine of you remove the built-in flash of course the next step is to use the inverse of that command but your unwillingness to follow simple instructions is a problem

Comment: Try manually downloading one of the Windows updates for it.  They're at the bottom of this page: http://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/kb/flash-player-issues-windows-8.html

Comment: Ok im trying active X of windows 7 finger crossed and ill try the update too i just want a working Active X dosent matter which one the inbuilt one or from abode.

Comment: Just stop asking him to "install" flash IT WILL NOT WORK!

Comment: I completed wiped out pre installed flash player from system and control panel using the tool idk if anyone knows how to get is back using same tool again

Comment: I read somewhere installing the update brings back flash player but it says package is not applicable although i downloaded right version so this ones not work

Comment: Horray! At least the IE based flash player from windows 7 worked. The flash for IE was listed under windows 7 section i was searching for 8 .Anyway my game works now still idk what should i do for inbuilt flash would this windows 7 IE flash be subustitue for the inbuilt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I extracted the [64Bit Version here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/zr7czfxtj2nmif0/Adobe-Flash-For-Windows-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.3.9600.16384.cab).

Download the file and run this command from a [cmd.exe which is started as admin](https://superuser.com/a/497256/174557):

```
DISM /Online /Add-Package /PackagePath:C:\Adobe-Flash-For-Windows-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.3.9600.16384.cab
```

Look if this works or not.

Comment: YESS!!!! WORKED PERFECTLY LIKE A CHARM . My flash player(32 bit) is back on control panel. Thanks all who helped.

Comment: nice to hear this. Mark the reply as answer to "close" this question.