# Windows 8 stop or start services from the command line

Tags: windows-8, command-line, services

I have a touch screen Windows 8 laptop, which has a touch screen keyboard that constantly shows up when I am working in metro apps. Is there a way to stop a service (specifically "Touch screen keyboard and handwriting panel" service) from the command line?

I know I can permanently stop the service from the service manager, but I am hoping to find a solution wherein I can create a shortcut to disable it, and another to re-enable it if needed.

Answer (score 3):

you can stop services via

```
net stop <servicename>
```

from a [command prompt with admin rights](https://superuser.com/questions/497252/how-to-access-the-administrator-command-prompt-in-windows-8)

So in your case:

```
net stop TabletInputService
```

and to start the service run this:

```
net start TabletInputService
```

Comment: Then of course Net Start to restart the service.

Comment: yeah, forgot to add this.

Answer (score 3):

Using PowerShell you can run the command `Stop-Service` or `Start-Service`. If you wanted to toggle between the two...

```
$service = Get-Service TabletInputService
if($service.status -eq "Running") {Stop-Service $service} else {Start-Service $service}
```

Drop that in PowerShell ISE and save it as a .ps1 and you should have a quick shortcut to alternate the service's state. I don't remember if writing your own script requires you to monkey with [Set-ExecutionPolicy](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176961.aspx), but you may have to loosen some restrictions to get the .ps1 to run without griping.

Comment: Powershell is King!

Answer (score 0):

I use a toggle shortcut. Save this to a .bat file in a safe place. Make a shortcut to it. Open properties, press advanced, tick "Run as administrator". Them move the shortcut somewhere convenient like the start menu.

```
for /F "tokens=3 delims=: " %%H in ('sc query "TabletInputService" ^| findstr "        STATE"') do (
  if /I "%%H" NEQ "RUNNING" (
    echo "enabling,"
    sc config "TabletInputService" start= demand
    sc start "TabletInputService"
  ) ELSE (
    echo "disabling,"
    sc config "TabletInputService" start= disabled
    sc stop "TabletInputService"
  )
)
```

Its ugly though. If only we could control windows with javascript.