# side-by-side config is incorrect

Tags: windows-8

I'm on Windows 8 64-bit. The game L.A. Noire is not running and SxSTrace.txt says:

```
================= Begin Activation Context Generation. Input Parameter:     Flags = 0   ProcessorArchitecture = Wow32   CultureFallBacks
= en-US;en  ManifestPath = C:\Program Files (x86)\Rockstar Games\L.A. Noire\LANoire.exe     AssemblyDirectory = C:\Program Files (x86)\Rockstar Games\L.A. Noire\   Application Config File = 
--------------- INFO: Parsing Manifest File C:\Program Files (x86)\Rockstar Games\L.A. Noire\LANoire.exe.   
                INFO: Manifest Definition Identity is (null).   
                INFO: Reference: Microsoft.VC90.CRT,processorArchitecture="x86",publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b",type="win32",version="9.0.21022.8"    
                INFO: Reference: Microsoft.VC90.MFC,processorArchitecture="x86",publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b",type="win32",version="9.0.21022.8" 
                INFO: Resolving reference Microsoft.VC90.CRT,processorArchitecture="x86",publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b",type="win32",version="9.0.21022.8".  
                INFO: Resolving reference for ProcessorArchitecture WOW64.      
                INFO: Resolving reference for culture Neutral.          
                INFO: Applying Binding Policy.
                INFO: No publisher policy found.
                INFO: No binding policy redirect found.             
                INFO: Begin assembly probing.
                INFO: Did not find the assembly in WinSxS.
                INFO: Attempt to probe manifest at C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_32\Microsoft.VC90.CRT\9.0.21022.8__1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b\Microsoft.VC90.CRT.DLL.
                INFO: Did not find manifest for culture Neutral.            
                INFO: End assembly probing.     
                INFO: Resolving reference for ProcessorArchitecture x86.        
                INFO: Resolving reference for culture Neutral.          
                INFO: Applying Binding Policy.
                INFO: Find publisher policy at C:\Windows\WinSxS\manifests\x86_policy.9.0.microsoft.vc90.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.30729.6871_none_f481befcf653ad33.manifest
                INFO: Publisher Policy redirected assembly version.
                INFO: Post policy assembly identity is Microsoft.VC90.CRT,processorArchitecture="x86",publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b",type="win32",version="9.0.30729.6871".          
                INFO: Begin assembly probing.
                INFO: Attempt to probe manifest at C:\Windows\WinSxS\manifests\x86_microsoft.vc90.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.30729.6871_none_50944e7cbcb706e5.manifest.
                INFO: Manifest found at C:\Windows\WinSxS\manifests\x86_microsoft.vc90.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.30729.6871_none_50944e7cbcb706e5.manifest.          
                INFO: End assembly probing. 
                INFO: Resolving reference Microsoft.VC90.CRT.mui,language="&#x2a;",processorArchitecture="x86",publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b",type="win32",version="9.0.30729.6871".     
                INFO: Resolving reference for ProcessorArchitecture WOW64.      
                INFO: Resolving reference for culture en-US.            
                INFO: Applying Binding Policy.
                INFO: No publisher policy found.
                INFO: No binding policy redirect found.             
                INFO: Begin assembly probing.
                INFO: Did not find the assembly in WinSxS.
                INFO: Attempt to probe manifest at C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_32\Microsoft.VC90.CRT.mui\9.0.30729.6871_en-US_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b\Microsoft.VC90.CRT.mui.DLL.
                INFO: Did not find manifest for culture en-US.          
                INFO: End assembly probing.         
                INFO: Resolving reference for culture en.           
                INFO: Applying Binding Policy.
                INFO: No publisher policy found.
                INFO: No binding policy redirect found.             
                INFO: Begin assembly probing.
                INFO: Did not find the assembly in WinSxS.
                INFO: Attempt to probe manifest at C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_32\Microsoft.VC90.CRT.mui\9.0.30729.6871_en_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b\Microsoft.VC90.CRT.mui.DLL.
                INFO: Did not find manifest for culture en.             
                INFO: End assembly probing.     
                INFO: Resolving reference for ProcessorArchitecture x86.        
                INFO: Resolving reference for culture en-US.            
                INFO: Applying Binding Policy.
                INFO: No publisher policy found.
                INFO: No binding policy redirect found.             
                INFO: Begin assembly probing.
                INFO: Did not find the assembly in WinSxS.
                INFO: Attempt to probe manifest at C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_32\Microsoft.VC90.CRT.mui\9.0.30729.6871_en-US_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b\Microsoft.VC90.CRT.mui.DLL.
                INFO: Did not find manifest for culture en-US.          
                INFO: End assembly probing.         
                INFO: Resolving reference for culture en.           
                INFO: Applying Binding Policy.
                INFO: No publisher policy found.
                INFO: No binding policy redirect found.             
                INFO: Begin assembly probing.
                INFO: Did not find the assembly in WinSxS.
                INFO: Attempt to probe manifest at C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_32\Microsoft.VC90.CRT.mui\9.0.30729.6871_en_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b\Microsoft.VC90.CRT.mui.DLL.
                INFO: Did not find manifest for culture en.             
                INFO: End assembly probing. 
                INFO: Resolving reference Microsoft.VC90.MFC,processorArchitecture="x86",publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b",type="win32",version="9.0.21022.8".  
                INFO: Resolving reference for ProcessorArchitecture WOW64.      
                INFO: Resolving reference for culture Neutral.          
                INFO: Applying Binding Policy.
                INFO: No publisher policy found.
                INFO: No binding policy redirect found.             
                INFO: Begin assembly probing.
                INFO: Did not find the assembly in WinSxS.
                INFO: Attempt to probe manifest at C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_32\Microsoft.VC90.MFC\9.0.21022.8__1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b\Microsoft.VC90.MFC.DLL.
                INFO: Did not find manifest for culture Neutral.            
                INFO: End assembly probing.     
                INFO: Resolving reference for ProcessorArchitecture x86.        
                INFO: Resolving reference for culture Neutral.          
                INFO: Applying Binding Policy.
                INFO: No publisher policy found.
                INFO: No binding policy redirect found.             
                INFO: Begin assembly probing.
                INFO: Did not find the assembly in WinSxS.
                INFO: Attempt to probe manifest at C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_32\Microsoft.VC90.MFC\9.0.21022.8__1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b\Microsoft.VC90.MFC.DLL.
                INFO: Attempt to probe manifest at C:\Program Files (x86)\Rockstar Games\L.A. Noire\Microsoft.VC90.MFC.DLL.
                INFO: Attempt to probe manifest at C:\Program Files (x86)\Rockstar Games\L.A. Noire\Microsoft.VC90.MFC.MANIFEST.
                INFO: Attempt to probe manifest at C:\Program Files (x86)\Rockstar Games\L.A. Noire\Microsoft.VC90.MFC\Microsoft.VC90.MFC.DLL.
                INFO: Attempt to probe manifest at C:\Program Files (x86)\Rockstar Games\L.A. Noire\Microsoft.VC90.MFC\Microsoft.VC90.MFC.MANIFEST.
                INFO: Did not find manifest for culture Neutral.            
                INFO: End assembly probing.     
                ERROR: Cannot resolve reference Microsoft.VC90.MFC,processorArchitecture="x86",publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b",type="win32",version="9.0.21022.8". 
                ERROR: Activation Context generation failed. End Activation Context Generation.
```

---

```
ERROR: Cannot resolve reference Microsoft.VC90.MFC,processorArchitecture="x86",publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b",type="win32",version="9.0.21022.8". 
ERROR: Activation Context generation failed. End Activation Context Generation.
```

Comment: guess recent installation of sanandreas sounds like a issue,your directory rockstar games says it,try again by removing it

Answer (score 1):

Please run this command from a [commandprompt with admin rights](https://superuser.com/questions/497252/how-to-access-the-administrator-command-prompt-in-windows-8)

```
DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth
```

Now check if this helps. If not, install the [Visual C++ 2008 Runtime](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29) again