# How do I uninstall skydrive and IE11 from windows 8.1?

Tags: internet-explorer, windows-8.1, onedrive

You can disable skydrive by going into the registry and disable IE by going into Turn windows features on or off but the thing is that I don't want Skydrive or IE.

I want to **remove** IE and skydrive from my computer.

Google told me that I can go to Control Panel → Programs and Features → Installed Updates and uninstall IE from there. However, there isn't an option to do so:

[image]

What do I do?

Comment: And *why* don't you want those products?

Comment: If you turn them off (in the case of IE) or disable them through the registry (in the case of Skydrive), what harm are they doing just sitting there? You're only going to save a few megabytes, at the most, by completely removing all traces of them.

Comment: Also, Windows has allowed you to [completely remove IE](http://winsupersite.com/windows-7/windows-7-feature-focus-internet-explorer-8) since Windows 7: "In Windows 7 only, Microsoft actually allows users to remove Internet Explorer 8 from the system, the first time it has allowed such a thing in about a decade."

Comment: @gparyani Because google [has](http://chrome.google.com) better [alternatives](http://drive.google.com)

Comment: @tapped-out I have an 256GB SSD, every megabyte is valuable.

Comment: @tapped-out That tutorial doesn't tell you how it just tells you that you can.

Comment: Contact Microsoft PSS for assistance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can officially uninstall the IE11 with DISM. First run

```
DISM.exe /Online /English /Get-Features /Format:Table
```

(from a [cmd.exe started as as admin](https://superuser.com/questions/497252/how-to-access-the-administrator-command-prompt-in-windows-8)) to get the name of all features. Remember what the correct name of the IE feature is.

Now run

```
DISM /Online /Disable-Feature /Featurename:Internet-Explorer-Optional-amd64  /Remove
```

(replace Internet-Explorer-Optional-amd64 with the name of the feature. I only have 8.0 here so I don't know if the name changed).

After a reboot, the IE is gone. If you activate the IE11 again in the `Turn Features on or off` dialog in Control Panel, Windows downloads the removed files and installs IE11 again.

Also look at the first command if there is a skydrive package. If there is one, repeat the steps for Skydrive. If not, you can't safely remove it.

Answer (score 0):

You can safely remove SkyDrive.  Since MS allows us to disable SkyDrive access via GP then I find it absolutely ridiculous that they don't just let us remove the Metro App since all it does is give an error.  The problem is, the package is hidden from us.  You can gain control of the registry settings required to unhide the package or just go download an app called "install_wim_tweak".

install_wim_tweak /o /n /c Microsoft-Windows-FileManager-Package

dism /Online /remove-package /packagename:Microsoft-Windows-FileManager-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.3.9600.16384

install_wim_tweak /o /h /n /c Microsoft-Windows-FileManager-Package

The package name is from my x64 Windows 8.1 Enterprise.  YMMV.  This will remove it from the local online image but not for any current user profiles.

Add that to the above DISM command for IE11 and you should be all set.  We remove all Metro apps along with the Photos and Skydrive app from all of our installs.  Works great!  Applying these commands to the install.wim of the install source makes for some great clean installs.