# Error Code Windows 8: 0x80070570

Tags: windows-8

When I try to create a directory or file in my Windows 8 system in the C drive, it pulls up this:

"An unexpected error is keeping you from creating the folder. If you continue to receive this error, you can use the error code to search for help with this problem. Error 0x80070570: The file or directory is corrupted and unreadable."

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 3):

Please open a [command prompt (cmd.exe) as admin](https://superuser.com/questions/497252/how-to-access-the-administrator-command-prompt-in-windows-8) and run chkdsk to detect and fix NTFS file system issues:

```
chkdsk /f /r C:\
```

Answer (score 0):

I got similar errors, while copyng files. Then I closed and re-openend explorer and the file was ok,but is really anoying.

Answer (score -1):

- Check Hard Disk for Errors
- Change Paging File Size
- Change File Security Settings
- Change Group Policy Editor Settings

www.ifixit.com/Wiki/Windows_8_NTFS_FILE_ERROR

Comment: Why would changing the paging file work? Change the security settings to what? What group policy should be edited?