# How do I activate Elevated Command Prompt? (Explorer.exe corrupted)

Tags: windows-8

My explorer.exe is corrupted. So I cannot activate elevated command prompt by right-clicking. I have the original explorer.exe but I cannot switch it back because I'm not in elevated command prompt.

I've tried net user administrator /active:yes, I get system error 5. I'm guessing because it's not elevated.

So how can I activate elevated command prompt if right-clicking isn't avail?

I don't have a USB either.

Comment: Select the CMD in start menu and then press Shift+ctrl+Enter and now your command prompt will open as admin.

Comment: I said my explorer.exe is corrupted, so I don't have a start menu. That's my problem.

Comment: You mean you have a opened command prompt window but it is not running as Admin, right?

Comment: See if this helps and report back: http://superuser.com/questions/497252/how-to-access-the-administrator-command-prompt-in-windows-8?rq=1

Comment: Again, explorer.exe is/was corrupted. Therefor, I couldn't access that. Luckily, when you're in task manager holding CTRL and clicking 
"Run new task" will open up elevated command prompt. Then I was able to restore my explorer.exe. 

Only problem is now, my desktop fades to black on Windows 8 unless I have a Window open. Startscreen works and all my icons are still on the desktop...

Comment: start the repair options when you boot from a Win8 DVD, select here the CMD prompt.