# Windows 8 - imagehlp.dll missing

Tags: windows, windows-8, dll

I've noticed that some of my icons have disappeared, but they still worked a while ago.

However, today when I booted my laptop, there was an error window similar to this
(my windows is finnish, so I'm having a bit trouble translating the error msgs):

`"Run32dll.exe - Error`
`imagehlp.dll is missing`

After I clicked 'ok' on the first one, another popped up, and this repeated for 5 times.

Also getting Origin update error and Steam 
`'there was a problem with your steam installation, Please reinstall steam'`

---

I've tried:

Fixing Steam (most of the solutions [here](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=1316865)) (No affect)

DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth (No affect)

Full virus/malware scan with IOBit Malware Fighter and F Secure (No results)

System restore (Does not even launch)

Install any available Windows updates (Only some Intel GPU driver, no affect)

Update drivers (All up-to-date)

SFC /scannow (No results, no affect)

chkdsk (/scan)(See below)

```
´Usn Journal verification completed.
The master file table's (MFT) BITMAP attribute is incorrect.
The Volume Bitmap is incorrect.
Windows has checked the file system and found problems.
Please run chkdsk /scan to find the problems and queue them for repair.
 470065151 KB total disk space.
 211851484 KB in 373518 files.
    224432 KB in 90233 indexes.
         0 KB in bad sectors.
    597155 KB in use by the system.
     65536 KB occupied by the log file.
 257392080 KB available on disk.
      4096 bytes in each allocation unit.
 117516287 total allocation units on disk.
  64348020 allocation units available on disk.´

C:\WINDOWS\system32>chkdsk /scan
Windows has scanned the file system and found no problems.
No further action is required.
Stage 1: Examining basic file system structure ...
 470065151 KB total disk space.; Stage: 72%; Total: 25%; ETA:   0:00:33 ...
 211957228 KB in 373521 files.
    224432 KB in 90233 indexes.
         0 KB in bad sectors.
    597667 KB in use by the system.
     65536 KB occupied by the log file.
 257285824 KB available on disk.

      4096 bytes in each allocation unit.
 117516287 total allocation units on disk.
  64321456 allocation units available on disk.
```

Please help, I wouldn't want to perform a clean install on my Windows 8.

Specs:
Fujitsu Lifebook AG523/G21
Windows 8
Core i7-3632QM
Intel HD Graphics 4000
Nvidia GeForce GTX620M
6GB RAM
500GB HDD

Comment: If I were to hazard to guess, your security software removed the dll, one simple solution is reinstall the programs in question.  Of course you might find it just easier to reinstall Windows.

Comment: Check for file-system/disk corruption (chkdsk).

Comment: @techie007 The results can be seen above now.

Comment: `Please run chkdsk /scan to find the problems and queue them for repair.` Did you do this: you said you did, but this message implies that you did not run it with the repair switch

Comment: @techie007 Updated. There's the results with that symptom.

Comment: If I recall correctly, using chkdsk with the "/R" option requires a locked drive and it should ask if you want ot run it at reboot. If you haven't run it with the repair option so that it checks before it boots windows, try that. Your scan output mentions files in use by the system. Not sure if that means they were skipped during scanning, and the problem you have seems to be a problem with "system files".

Answer (score 0):

Open a [command prompt as admin](https://superuser.com/questions/497252/how-to-access-the-administrator-command-prompt-in-windows-8) and run [this DISM command](http://blogs.technet.com/b/joscon/archive/2012/09/26/fixing-component-store-corruption-in-windows-8-and-windows-server-2012.aspx) to restore the missing Windows DLL:

```
DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth
```

Now look if all files are restored.

Comment: Absolutely no affect.