# Can't run Hyper-V after changing to SSD

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, hyper-v, emulator, windows-phone

I swapped out my HDD for a Samsung 840 EVO SSD, and migrated my OS using Samsung's Data Migration Program. I had Visual Studio 2013 installed with the Windows Phone SDK 8.0, and I was able to run all emulators normally on the HDD. However, the emulators will not start on my SSDs, and I'm getting the message "hypervisor isn't running". I have hardware virtualization enabled on my BIOS, is it just that the emulators won't run on the SSD?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You miss the BCD entry to load the Hyper-V driver. [Open a command prompt as admin](https://superuser.com/a/497256/174557) and run this command:

```
bcdedit /set {current} hypervisorlaunchtype auto
```

reboot and the Hypervisor driver is loaded.

Comment: Excellent! It worked perfectly :)

Comment: Fantastic, had the same problem after cloning a disk and this solution worked