# How can I fix Windows Defender error code in Windows 8.1?

Tags: windows-8.1, boot, windows-defender

Windows Defender is giving me an error code 0x80073b01 and it will not start. I am not sure if this is caused by the OS language change that I did recently but I did a scan for virsuses with Norton 360 and found none.  I cannot get Windows Defender offline to work either.  Windows will start to load from a USB stick, but never completes.

Answer (score 1):

The Error code means `ERROR_MUI_FILE_NOT_LOADED` :

```
C:\Users\André>err 0x80073b01
# as an HRESULT: Severity: FAILURE (1), FACILITY_WIN32 (0x7), Code 0x3b01
# for hex 0x3b01 / decimal 15105
  ERROR_MUI_FILE_NOT_LOADED                                      winerror.h
# The resource loader cache doesn't have loaded MUI entry.
# 1 matches found for "0x80073b01"
```

Open a [command prompt as admin](https://superuser.com/a/497256/174557) and run this DISM command to [detect and repair missing Windows files](http://blogs.technet.com/b/joscon/archive/2012/09/26/fixing-component-store-corruption-in-windows-8-and-windows-server-2012.aspx):

```
DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth
```