# Any solution appeared to fix win 8.1 drivers disaster? (keyboard stopped to work)

Tags: drivers, keyboard, windows-8.1

Win 8.1 never stops to impress me. This is already third time such disaster happened to me.
Before that I was using system refresh to "reinstall" windows, but I tired :/

Ok, the problem... my ps/2 keyboard stopped to work again, but this time with audio device.
In previous time it was keyboard only and mouse and keyboard.

In device manager those devices marked with yellow mark.

[image]

If I open device properties I see this:

[image]

(looks like windows programmers forgor to add variables in printf functions, so only type specifiers is shown.)

Ok, next.
What I tried to do:
**delete device and restart windows** - does not helps, the same yellow marked device is found after startup.

**Roll back driver** - this buttons is not active.

**Automatic driver update** - says that driver update is not needed.
[image]

**Manual driver installation with the choice of the only single driver available in the list**:
[image]

**Delete device from manager, plug keyboard off PC. Shutdown PC. Start PC and plug keyboard in PC** - nothing happens.

I found some thread in Internet about **UpperFilters and LowerFilters**. In my registry there was no such keys, so nothing to delete.

Also I found thread with some **.reg files** to fix dvd drive and keyboard issues. I tried those, but no help.

Tried some **auto driver installations programs** - they do not list yellow marked devices as needed for update.

I read some threads about **disabling XHCI Mode** in bios, but i have real BIOS, not UEFI, so i don't have this setting present.

I tried to run command: **sfc.exe /scannow**
In the end it said that problems are found and unable to fix.

I am programmer, my pc is clean enough. I don't download junk progs, don't visit port sites and warez sites, don't use optimizers and etc.

Yesterday i didn't installed anything, i just shutdown my PC and today the keyboard not work.
**The keyboard work in bios time only**, once OS is starting to load, it stops to work, so I can't even press F8 for safe mode.
Keyboard also works in bootable CDs and Linux Live CDs.

Now i plugged bluetooth keyboard and gladly it works, but it from tablet PC and so uncomfortable to use.

I really don't want to reinstall windows again. Just week passes since second time when no keyboard and mouse were working and a year since forst time.

From windows logs:
*Device ACPI\PNP0303\4&224ad326&0 had a problem starting.

Driver Name: keyboard.inf

Class Guid: {4d36e96b-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}

Service: i8042prt

Lower Filters: 

Upper Filters: 

Problem: 0x27

Status: 0x0*

**Result of sfc.exe:**
*Beginning system scan.  This process will take some time.
Beginning verification phase of system scan.
Verification 100% complete.
Windows Resource Protection found corrupt files but was unable to fix some
of them. Details are included in the CBS.Log windir\Logs\CBS\CBS.log. For
example C:\Windows\Logs\CBS\CBS.log. Note that logging is currently not
supported in offline servicing scenarios.*

This is the link for logs http://fbe.am/sof.
there was something wrong with logs, so i placed all files presented there in folder and run command second time. Still, the log much lesser than before created. Maybe worth to read logs dated 22 April in that folder I created.

Could anyone help me with anything?
This is definetly win 8.1 drivers problem. Not a keyboard.

Comment: There seems to be some issues with the **High Definition Audio Device** too. Copy the `CBS.log` file located in `C:\Windows\Logs\CBS` to the desktop, compress it in a .zip/.7z archive and upload it somewhere (e.g. http://ge.tt/about). Then post here the link.

Comment: Yea. Sound also gone this time, but this is the least problem, if compare to keyboard. Looks like this log is overwriten by something. I already read it and it was a couple of MBs, now only 70 kb. i will run that command again and upload the result soon.

Comment: @and31415 - I did what you said.

Comment: Have you verified the system integrity by using `sfc` and `DISM`?

Comment: By sfc you mean something other than what I run? I used "sfc.exe /scannall" and I don't know anything about DISM. It looks like about WinPE for me.

Comment: @Kosmos I've posted an answer which can help you understand which are the corrupted files. Before proceeding with manual repairs, open a command prompt as administrator and run this command: `chkdsk %systemdrive% /r`. It will ask you to schedule a disk check next time Windows starts. After giving the required confirmation, restart Windows and wait for the disk check to finish. Report back any errors that maybe be detected.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I will try it and see what happens.

Comment: @Kosmos To get the proper files you'll need a Windows 8.1 setup media. In case you don't have one, you can get the [official trial](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/evalcenter/hh699156.aspx). Just make sure to get the same version you have installed (e.g. 32-bit). I'll add the repair steps later on. By the way, the keyboard-related driver `i8042prt.sys` is indeed corrupted.

Comment: What is the make and model of your computer?

Comment: This is custom made by me computer from chosen by me parts. it work fine for a 4 years and will continue to work fine if I refresh windows 8.1, which I don't want that much.

Comment: because there is no guaranty that KB will continue to work after week or two passed.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem? Tough nut.

Comment: @MilindR - No, this is crazy tough nut. I described the most fast fix in my own answer, about "repair" with keeping everything. Also, I started to do Windows backup images and restoring to those once in a month, after something broke. Also, I talked long with MS support guys, but they were unable to solve this too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For now, there is no known solutions. BUT, it possible to repair windows 8.1 in the good old meaning of that word.
You can download upgrade assistant or get an ISO of win 8.1 and run it or installer under loaded win 8.1. Follow steps and choose "Keep Windows settings, personal files, and apps" while passing through steps. At final stage windows will start installation and keep EVERYTHING! It much better than Refresh, so, it's the best current solution.

However... if not work mouse + KB, it's really hard to do so, because windows installer must be started from running windows.

Answer (score 5):

In Windows 8(.1) you can use [DISM to repair corrupted files](http://blogs.technet.com/b/joscon/archive/2012/09/26/fixing-component-store-corruption-in-windows-8-and-windows-server-2012.aspx) by running this command from an [elevated CMD prompt](https://superuser.com/a/497256/174557):

```
DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth
```

If it detects corrupted files that it can't repair, Windows downloads the files from Windows Update. So there is NO need to repair files yourself like in Vista/Windows 7.

Comment: Thank you. Now I trying this. Currently in stuck at 20% for 10 minutes already.

Comment: Don't know what to think. The program finished. I gone to device manager and deleted keyboard and audio. restarted PC. keyboard and audio still don't work. and i can't install or reinstall drivers because of reasons in main question >_<

Comment: @Kosmos upload the new CBS logs and also the DISM.log.

Comment: The first time I run dism it ended without errors, now I decided to run in second time, but it ended with error, however, created some logs http://fbe.am/spq: Deployment Image Servicing and Management tool
Version: 6.3.9600.17031

Image Version: 6.3.9600.17031

[==========================100.0%==========================]

Error: 0x80240021

DISM failed. No operation was performed.
For more information, review the log file.

The DISM log file can be found at C:\WINDOWS\Logs\DISM\dism.log

Comment: @Kosmos the portcls.sys in version 6.3.9600.17031 is corrupted and Windows has a timeout to download the file. You can downlaod an 8.1 ISO which includes the Update like the Enterprise Trial. Now use the /Source parameter to point to the WIM to get the data if download fails all the time. The other issues were all fixed by DISM.

Comment: Is this correct usage of Source? "C:\WINDOWS\system32>DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth /Source=H:\sources\install.wim". It ended with same error in the end.

Comment: this is the correct syntax:  /source:wim:c:\install.wim:2 /limitaccess (where number is the WIM index of the image in the WIM file that contains the source of the feature payload)

Comment: Windows update repair wizard said that fixed some errors, after that dism ended with success, but... again KB don't work and no sound. Deleting and "scan for hardware changes" gives same yellow marked devices. The logs: http://fbe.am/sr7

Comment: according to the last logs, DISM was able to repair all files

Comment: yea, but according by not working KB, there is still something wrong. Kb works in bios and windows repair mode at startup, if I change startup settings.

Comment: remove all broken devices again, let Windows reinstall them and if they still don't work, share all setupapi logs from **C:\Windows\Inf**

Comment: renamed the logs that was there before. deleted broken devices. scanned pc for hardware changes. also tried to manually install KB driver and via auto update. http://fbe.am/stN Appears to be some sys without signature, but I don't know how that could be if dism fixed all.

Comment: Activate the highest logging (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff550808%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), try to install the drivers again and give me the new setupAPI logs.

Comment: 0x000000FF this is highest?

Comment: 0x0000FFFF is highest.

Comment: okey, will do now. the current value is: 20004001 (hex) and i think this is weird

Comment: create the loglevel values if it is not there.

Comment: the logs are here: http://fbe.am/stQ however, they are so small. I don't think is were higher logging

Comment: try 0x7070 as loglevel

Comment: that http://fbe.am/stR ones is bigger a few.

Comment: I still have no idea. it shows a PNP problem ("Queueing up error report since device has a PnP problem" and "Device not started: Device has problem: 0x27: CM_PROB_DRIVER_FAILED_LOAD". Try the good old Inplace uprade: http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/3413-repair-install.html

Comment: yea, this is all weird and like a plague spread around win 8.1 users. I will wait for some another solution a bit more. If no - Refresh windows again. Thank you for spending you time in attempts to help me.

Answer (score 3):

## Filtering the details

Running the `sfc /scannow` will produce a `CBS.log` report file (usually found in `C:\Windows\Logs\CBS`) which contains a wealth of information. In order to get the juicy bits, open a command prompt, and execute this command:

```
findstr /i /c:"[SR]" "%windir%\Logs\CBS\CBS.log" | findstr /i /v /c:"verify" > "%userprofile%\Desktop\sfc.txt"
```

The above command will:

1. Get all lines in the original file containing `[SR]`, which are the ones that track the repair attempts.
2. Remove all lines containing `verify` from what we got in the previous step in order to further reduce the clutter.
3. Write the results in the `sfc.txt` file for later analysis.

In this case, this would be the resulting file:

```
2014-04-22 17:07:44, Info                  CSI    00000065 [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:22{11}]"HdAudio.sys" of hdaudio.inf, Version = 6.3.9600.16384, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_INTEL (0), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type = [l:24{12}]"driverUpdate", TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral in the store, hash mismatch
2014-04-22 17:07:48, Info                  CSI    00000067 [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:22{11}]"HdAudio.sys" of hdaudio.inf, Version = 6.3.9600.16384, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_INTEL (0), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type = [l:24{12}]"driverUpdate", TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral in the store, hash mismatch
2014-04-22 17:07:48, Info                  CSI    00000068 [SR] This component was referenced by [l:194{97}]"Microsoft-Windows-Client-Drivers-Package-drivers~31bf3856ad364e35~x86~~6.3.9600.16384.INF_hdaudio"
2014-04-22 17:07:49, Info                  CSI    0000006d [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:24{12}]"i8042prt.sys" of keyboard.inf, Version = 6.3.9600.16384, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_INTEL (0), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type = [l:24{12}]"driverUpdate", TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral in the store, hash mismatch
2014-04-22 17:07:57, Info                  CSI    0000006f [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:24{12}]"i8042prt.sys" of keyboard.inf, Version = 6.3.9600.16384, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_INTEL (0), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type = [l:24{12}]"driverUpdate", TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral in the store, hash mismatch
2014-04-22 17:07:57, Info                  CSI    00000070 [SR] This component was referenced by [l:196{98}]"Microsoft-Windows-Common-Drivers-Package-drivers~31bf3856ad364e35~x86~~6.3.9600.16384.INF_keyboard"
2014-04-22 17:08:01, Info                  CSI    00000075 [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:24{12}]"mdmhandy.inf" of mdmhandy.inf, Version = 6.3.9600.16384, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_INTEL (0), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type = [l:24{12}]"driverUpdate", TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral in the store, hash mismatch
2014-04-22 17:08:05, Info                  CSI    00000077 [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:24{12}]"mdmhandy.inf" of mdmhandy.inf, Version = 6.3.9600.16384, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_INTEL (0), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type = [l:24{12}]"driverUpdate", TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral in the store, hash mismatch
2014-04-22 17:08:05, Info                  CSI    00000078 [SR] This component was referenced by [l:200{100}]"Microsoft-Windows-Common-Modem-Drivers-Package-net~31bf3856ad364e35~x86~~6.3.9600.16384.INF_mdmhandy"
2014-04-22 17:16:44, Info                  CSI    00000442 [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:24{12}]"i8042prt.sys" of msmouse.inf, Version = 6.3.9600.16384, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_INTEL (0), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type = [l:24{12}]"driverUpdate", TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral in the store, hash mismatch
2014-04-22 17:16:47, Info                  CSI    00000444 [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:24{12}]"i8042prt.sys" of msmouse.inf, Version = 6.3.9600.16384, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_INTEL (0), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type = [l:24{12}]"driverUpdate", TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral in the store, hash mismatch
2014-04-22 17:16:47, Info                  CSI    00000445 [SR] This component was referenced by [l:194{97}]"Microsoft-Windows-Common-Drivers-Package-drivers~31bf3856ad364e35~x86~~6.3.9600.16384.INF_msmouse"
2014-04-22 17:17:42, Info                  CSI    00000479 [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:22{11}]"netr28u.sys" of netr28u.inf, Version = 6.3.9600.16384, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_INTEL (0), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type = [l:24{12}]"driverUpdate", TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral in the store, hash mismatch
2014-04-22 17:17:46, Info                  CSI    0000047b [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:22{11}]"netr28u.sys" of netr28u.inf, Version = 6.3.9600.16384, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_INTEL (0), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type = [l:24{12}]"driverUpdate", TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral in the store, hash mismatch
2014-04-22 17:17:46, Info                  CSI    0000047c [SR] This component was referenced by [l:194{97}]"Microsoft-Windows-Client-Drivers-Package-drivers~31bf3856ad364e35~x86~~6.3.9600.16384.INF_netr28u"
2014-04-22 17:18:37, Info                  CSI    0000048c [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:24{12}]"uaspstor.sys" of uaspstor.inf, Version = 6.3.9600.16384, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_INTEL (0), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type = [l:24{12}]"driverUpdate", TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral in the store, hash mismatch
2014-04-22 17:18:38, Info                  CSI    0000048e [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:24{12}]"uaspstor.sys" of uaspstor.inf, Version = 6.3.9600.16384, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_INTEL (0), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type = [l:24{12}]"driverUpdate", TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral in the store, hash mismatch
2014-04-22 17:18:38, Info                  CSI    0000048f [SR] This component was referenced by [l:196{98}]"Microsoft-Windows-Common-Drivers-Package-drivers~31bf3856ad364e35~x86~~6.3.9600.16384.INF_uaspstor"
2014-04-22 17:18:42, Info                  CSI    00000494 [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:22{11}]"portcls.sys" of wdmaudio.inf, Version = 6.3.9600.17031, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_INTEL (0), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type = [l:24{12}]"driverUpdate", TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral in the store, hash mismatch
2014-04-22 17:18:44, Info                  CSI    00000496 [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:22{11}]"portcls.sys" of wdmaudio.inf, Version = 6.3.9600.17031, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_INTEL (0), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type = [l:24{12}]"driverUpdate", TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral in the store, hash mismatch
2014-04-22 17:18:44, Info                  CSI    00000497 [SR] This component was referenced by [l:162{81}]"Package_939_for_KB2919355~31bf3856ad364e35~x86~~6.3.1.14.2919355-2269_neutral_GDR"
2014-04-22 17:19:11, Info                  CSI    000004a3 [SR] Repairing 7 components
2014-04-22 17:19:11, Info                  CSI    000004a6 [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:22{11}]"HdAudio.sys" of hdaudio.inf, Version = 6.3.9600.16384, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_INTEL (0), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type = [l:24{12}]"driverUpdate", TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral in the store, hash mismatch
2014-04-22 17:19:11, Info                  CSI    000004a8 [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:24{12}]"i8042prt.sys" of keyboard.inf, Version = 6.3.9600.16384, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_INTEL (0), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type = [l:24{12}]"driverUpdate", TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral in the store, hash mismatch
2014-04-22 17:19:11, Info                  CSI    000004aa [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:24{12}]"mdmhandy.inf" of mdmhandy.inf, Version = 6.3.9600.16384, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_INTEL (0), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type = [l:24{12}]"driverUpdate", TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral in the store, hash mismatch
2014-04-22 17:19:11, Info                  CSI    000004ac [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:24{12}]"i8042prt.sys" of msmouse.inf, Version = 6.3.9600.16384, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_INTEL (0), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type = [l:24{12}]"driverUpdate", TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral in the store, hash mismatch
2014-04-22 17:19:12, Info                  CSI    000004ae [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:22{11}]"netr28u.sys" of netr28u.inf, Version = 6.3.9600.16384, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_INTEL (0), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type = [l:24{12}]"driverUpdate", TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral in the store, hash mismatch
2014-04-22 17:19:12, Info                  CSI    000004b0 [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:24{12}]"uaspstor.sys" of uaspstor.inf, Version = 6.3.9600.16384, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_INTEL (0), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type = [l:24{12}]"driverUpdate", TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral in the store, hash mismatch
2014-04-22 17:19:12, Info                  CSI    000004b2 [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:22{11}]"portcls.sys" of wdmaudio.inf, Version = 6.3.9600.17031, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_INTEL (0), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type = [l:24{12}]"driverUpdate", TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral in the store, hash mismatch
2014-04-22 17:19:12, Info                  CSI    000004b4 [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:24{12}]"uaspstor.sys" of uaspstor.inf, Version = 6.3.9600.16384, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_INTEL (0), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type = [l:24{12}]"driverUpdate", TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral in the store, hash mismatch
2014-04-22 17:19:12, Info                  CSI    000004b5 [SR] This component was referenced by [l:196{98}]"Microsoft-Windows-Common-Drivers-Package-drivers~31bf3856ad364e35~x86~~6.3.9600.16384.INF_uaspstor"
2014-04-22 17:19:12, Info                  CSI    000004b7 [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:22{11}]"netr28u.sys" of netr28u.inf, Version = 6.3.9600.16384, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_INTEL (0), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type = [l:24{12}]"driverUpdate", TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral in the store, hash mismatch
2014-04-22 17:19:12, Info                  CSI    000004b8 [SR] This component was referenced by [l:194{97}]"Microsoft-Windows-Client-Drivers-Package-drivers~31bf3856ad364e35~x86~~6.3.9600.16384.INF_netr28u"
2014-04-22 17:19:12, Info                  CSI    000004ba [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:24{12}]"i8042prt.sys" of keyboard.inf, Version = 6.3.9600.16384, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_INTEL (0), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type = [l:24{12}]"driverUpdate", TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral in the store, hash mismatch
2014-04-22 17:19:12, Info                  CSI    000004bb [SR] This component was referenced by [l:196{98}]"Microsoft-Windows-Common-Drivers-Package-drivers~31bf3856ad364e35~x86~~6.3.9600.16384.INF_keyboard"
2014-04-22 17:19:12, Info                  CSI    000004bd [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:22{11}]"HdAudio.sys" of hdaudio.inf, Version = 6.3.9600.16384, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_INTEL (0), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type = [l:24{12}]"driverUpdate", TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral in the store, hash mismatch
2014-04-22 17:19:12, Info                  CSI    000004be [SR] This component was referenced by [l:194{97}]"Microsoft-Windows-Client-Drivers-Package-drivers~31bf3856ad364e35~x86~~6.3.9600.16384.INF_hdaudio"
2014-04-22 17:19:12, Info                  CSI    000004c0 [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:22{11}]"portcls.sys" of wdmaudio.inf, Version = 6.3.9600.17031, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_INTEL (0), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type = [l:24{12}]"driverUpdate", TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral in the store, hash mismatch
2014-04-22 17:19:12, Info                  CSI    000004c1 [SR] This component was referenced by [l:162{81}]"Package_939_for_KB2919355~31bf3856ad364e35~x86~~6.3.1.14.2919355-2269_neutral_GDR"
2014-04-22 17:19:12, Info                  CSI    000004c3 [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:24{12}]"mdmhandy.inf" of mdmhandy.inf, Version = 6.3.9600.16384, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_INTEL (0), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type = [l:24{12}]"driverUpdate", TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral in the store, hash mismatch
2014-04-22 17:19:12, Info                  CSI    000004c4 [SR] This component was referenced by [l:200{100}]"Microsoft-Windows-Common-Modem-Drivers-Package-net~31bf3856ad364e35~x86~~6.3.9600.16384.INF_mdmhandy"
2014-04-22 17:19:12, Info                  CSI    000004c6 [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:24{12}]"i8042prt.sys" of msmouse.inf, Version = 6.3.9600.16384, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_INTEL (0), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type = [l:24{12}]"driverUpdate", TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral in the store, hash mismatch
2014-04-22 17:19:12, Info                  CSI    000004c7 [SR] This component was referenced by [l:194{97}]"Microsoft-Windows-Common-Drivers-Package-drivers~31bf3856ad364e35~x86~~6.3.9600.16384.INF_msmouse"
2014-04-22 17:19:12, Info                  CSI    000004c8 [SR] Repair complete
2014-04-22 17:19:12, Info                  CSI    000004c9 [SR] Committing transaction
```

## Identifying the issues

Checking the file you can see the System File Checker tried to repair 7 components, but failed:

```
2014-04-22 17:19:11, Info                  CSI    000004a3 [SR] Repairing 7 components
2014-04-22 17:19:12, Info                  CSI    000004b4 [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:24{12}]"uaspstor.sys" of uaspstor.inf, Version = 6.3.9600.16384, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_INTEL (0), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type = [l:24{12}]"driverUpdate", TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral in the store, hash mismatch
2014-04-22 17:19:12, Info                  CSI    000004b5 [SR] This component was referenced by [l:196{98}]"Microsoft-Windows-Common-Drivers-Package-drivers~31bf3856ad364e35~x86~~6.3.9600.16384.INF_uaspstor"
2014-04-22 17:19:12, Info                  CSI    000004b7 [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:22{11}]"netr28u.sys" of netr28u.inf, Version = 6.3.9600.16384, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_INTEL (0), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type = [l:24{12}]"driverUpdate", TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral in the store, hash mismatch
2014-04-22 17:19:12, Info                  CSI    000004b8 [SR] This component was referenced by [l:194{97}]"Microsoft-Windows-Client-Drivers-Package-drivers~31bf3856ad364e35~x86~~6.3.9600.16384.INF_netr28u"
2014-04-22 17:19:12, Info                  CSI    000004ba [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:24{12}]"i8042prt.sys" of keyboard.inf, Version = 6.3.9600.16384, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_INTEL (0), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type = [l:24{12}]"driverUpdate", TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral in the store, hash mismatch
2014-04-22 17:19:12, Info                  CSI    000004bb [SR] This component was referenced by [l:196{98}]"Microsoft-Windows-Common-Drivers-Package-drivers~31bf3856ad364e35~x86~~6.3.9600.16384.INF_keyboard"
2014-04-22 17:19:12, Info                  CSI    000004bd [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:22{11}]"HdAudio.sys" of hdaudio.inf, Version = 6.3.9600.16384, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_INTEL (0), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type = [l:24{12}]"driverUpdate", TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral in the store, hash mismatch
2014-04-22 17:19:12, Info                  CSI    000004be [SR] This component was referenced by [l:194{97}]"Microsoft-Windows-Client-Drivers-Package-drivers~31bf3856ad364e35~x86~~6.3.9600.16384.INF_hdaudio"
2014-04-22 17:19:12, Info                  CSI    000004c0 [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:22{11}]"portcls.sys" of wdmaudio.inf, Version = 6.3.9600.17031, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_INTEL (0), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type = [l:24{12}]"driverUpdate", TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral in the store, hash mismatch
2014-04-22 17:19:12, Info                  CSI    000004c1 [SR] This component was referenced by [l:162{81}]"Package_939_for_KB2919355~31bf3856ad364e35~x86~~6.3.1.14.2919355-2269_neutral_GDR"
2014-04-22 17:19:12, Info                  CSI    000004c3 [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:24{12}]"mdmhandy.inf" of mdmhandy.inf, Version = 6.3.9600.16384, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_INTEL (0), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type = [l:24{12}]"driverUpdate", TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral in the store, hash mismatch
2014-04-22 17:19:12, Info                  CSI    000004c4 [SR] This component was referenced by [l:200{100}]"Microsoft-Windows-Common-Modem-Drivers-Package-net~31bf3856ad364e35~x86~~6.3.9600.16384.INF_mdmhandy"
2014-04-22 17:19:12, Info                  CSI    000004c6 [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:24{12}]"i8042prt.sys" of msmouse.inf, Version = 6.3.9600.16384, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_INTEL (0), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type = [l:24{12}]"driverUpdate", TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral in the store, hash mismatch
2014-04-22 17:19:12, Info                  CSI    000004c7 [SR] This component was referenced by [l:194{97}]"Microsoft-Windows-Common-Drivers-Package-drivers~31bf3856ad364e35~x86~~6.3.9600.16384.INF_msmouse"
```

Each entry follows this rough scheme:

- `Cannot repair member file [...]"uaspstor.sys"`
  The file that needs to be repaired.
- `of uaspstor.inf,`
  The name of the package which the file belongs to.
- `Version = 6.3.9600.16384,`
  File version (major, minor, build and revision).
- `pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_INTEL (0),`
  The targeted [processor architecture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724958%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).
- `Culture neutral, [...],`
  Either neutral or the related [culture name](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb896001.aspx) if localized.
- `hash mismatch`
  Reason the file need to be repaired.

While the listed files are there, their hash doesn't match the expected value which means they are corrupted. All files except one share the same version, i.e. `6.3.9600.16384`. This means they are included as part of Windows 8.1 RTM. The `portcls.sys` file has version `6.3.9600.17031` and it is part of the [KB2919355](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2919355) update:

```
2014-04-22 17:19:12, Info                  CSI    000004c1 [SR] This component was referenced by [l:162{81}]"Package_939_for_KB2919355~31bf3856ad364e35~x86~~6.3.1.14.2919355-2269_neutral_GDR"
```

At this point you need to replace the corrupted files.

## References

- [Use the System File Checker tool to repair missing or corrupted system files](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929833/en-us)
- [How to Run "SFC /SCANNOW" Command at Boot or in Windows 8 and 8.1](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/3047-sfc-scannow-command-run-windows-8-a.html)

Comment: Do I need to replace files in all 3 folders where they currently presented? Screen: http://filebeam.com/1051fababcda2f9fe1607a13c7cd4f0f.jpg

Comment: @Kosmos Actually they're meant to be [hard links](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_link), and they should be identical. You just need to replace the copy located in `C:\Windows\WinSxS`. After you replaced everything, run `sfc /scannow` which should repair the other copies as needed and ensure there are no further issues.

Comment: Ok, will start searching for that files in installation media. chkdsk was work very long at startup. I though it hanged at 10%. It were in such state for 30 minutes, then accidentally finished all and loaded. I can't find chkdsk log, however.

Comment: err, it seems that installation media do not contain those files in free-to-find form. Windows search can't find any of that sys files on disk.

Comment: @Kosmos The `chkdsk` log should be available in the Event Viewer. See [CHKDSK - Check a Drive for Errors in Windows 8](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/6221-chkdsk-check-drive-errors-windows-8-a.html). As for the files, check this article: [How to Extract Files from the Windows 7 Installation DVD](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/42776-extract-files-windows-7-installation-dvd.html). I'm still going to edit my questions to later in order to include the step-by-step repair process. Let me know if you have any other questions in the meanwhile.

Comment: This is weird, but i don't see any event with "chkdsk" source as shown on the screen on the link you gave me. Reading guide about files extraction...

Comment: You know a way to replace files? I can't do that. I even tried to boot windows live CD, but it says "access denied" when I trying to replace files. And, of course, I can't to it in current OS with same reason. Do I need to download some linux live iso?

Comment: I don't think that was the best way, but I succeeded in it. I seized the control over each folder where files I need to replace is placed and changed permissions. Sadly, I can't change owner back to TrustedInstaller. Currently sfc finishes it's work. Will see what happens next.

Comment: Strange. sfc finished it's work and still said that unable to fix some errors. I executed findstr /i /c:"[SR]" "%windir%\Logs\CBS\CBS.log" | findstr /i /v /c:"verify" > "%userprofile%\Desktop\sfc.txt" but this time it gave me empty file and keyboard and audio still don't work. tried to reinstall drivers through manager too. fails with same reasons as before.

Comment: here http://fbe.am/soN

Comment: @Kosmos There are no more corrupted files, however there are still hundreds of warnings: http://pastebin.com/NZJfTQiT Apparently there are some issues with the ownership/security permissions of many system folders.

Comment: For now, I will uncheck the answer, in hope to get more attention from others. Regarding the wrong permissions, there is nothing I can do. I read over Internet that error code 39 in device manager can be caused by registry errors too.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14084/discussion-between-and31415-and-kosmos)

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to hear about your troubles with Windows 8.1!  I've seen this before on a machine and I found the answer on a TomsHardware forum - http://www.tomshardware.com/answers/id-1946297/keyboard-working-windows.html

Can you check the service startup status for "i8042prt" - this is a hidden system service, so it can't be found in "services.msc".

Go into Regedit, and go to:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\i8042prt

What value is the service on?  Take note, then turn the StartValue to 1, reboot the PC and see how you go.  If it doesn't help, you can change it back.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for response. How lucky those guys are that this helped them. For me does not work. The value were set to 3. I set to 1. restarted - Kb still yellow. Deleted it, restarted, KB yellow again. Nothing helps :(

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes its just driver's fault. And [DriverPack](http://drpsu.com) has helped me a lot.
Download the [lite](http://drpsu.com/download.htm) version and let it check and update your drivers automatically.

Comment: Yes, but driver pack solutions included into: **Tried some auto driver installations programs** - they do not list yellow marked devices as needed for update.

Comment: Sorry, you didn't mention which ones you used, so I thought you could miss this.

Comment: P.S. -1 is not from me. And there is general reason for why any auto drivers update software will fail - the current drivers is okey for device, they just can't be loaded, while they are the most up to date.