# Windows 8.1 Update 1 showing activation error

Tags: windows-8, installation, windows-8.1

I have installed Windows 8.1 Update 1 Pro Version a few weeks back on my desktop computer running 64 bit version of the OS. The OS was running perfectly fine until today when it started showing activation error. This is not right since I had installed Windows 8.1 Update 1 with a legit key since I have an MSDN subscription

As you can see in below pic. It says that you can activate the Windows Machine now

[image]

Now I went ahead and tried to activate the windows by the key which I had intially activated and **also with a new fresh different key which I haven't any activated windows machine yet**. Both the steps didn't yield any fruitful results

Please find below snapshot that show how weird my machine behaves.

1) When I hit "Activate" button

[image]

2) When I click "Error Details"

[image]

3) When I click "See Support info online" - Nothing happens

I have tried below troubleshooting steps but nothing happened yet

- Run sfc/scannow command. This failed at 42%
- Tried to scan registry and fix the registry by using Advanced System Care 7.2 Pro Edition
- Refresh the PC. PC was unable to refresh. I had inserted my OS USB Drive
- Tried System Restore to yesterday state. System Restore too failed
- Uninstalled Windows Updates that were installed yesterday.

Please suggest how should I move forward with this. I would want to avoid/make it as a last option a fresh install in PC.

**UPDATE-1**: Getting below error when tried slmgr.vbs -ato

[image]

**UPDATE-2**: Error after running DISM Command

[image]

Thanks

Comment: 'smlgr.vbs' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Comment: small typo. it is **slmgr.vbs -ato**

Comment: @magicandre1981: Question updated with the error.

Comment: ok, the error means **SL_E_SFS_INVALID_TOKEN_DATA_HASH - The Software Licensing Service reported that a token in the Token Store contains an invalid hash** You have corrupted system files. Use DISM instead of sfc to fix it: http://superuser.com/a/744714/174557

Comment: @magicandre1981: Should I run DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth command

Comment: @magicandre1981:Update-2 showing error after running DISM Command

Comment: @magicandre1981: Any inputs?

Comment: can you share the dism.log? Have you disabled any services like the trusted installer (Windows Modules Installer)?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, did you check your hard drive for errors?  Perhaps your drive is failing and that's causing corruption of the system files.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and the same worries. I did nothing, then suddenly, after a week or two, the activation message stopped appearing. Hopefully it's just a glitch in the W8.1 activation logic.

Comment: So you are suggesting that I should avoid Windows 8.1 reset?

Comment: @RomilN - I agree.  Your system image integrity is a problem.  I actually would reset your image.  Because you should be able to activate Windows or at the very least change the license to a generic license and change it back which based on the supplied screenshots you won't be able to do because of the corruption.

Comment: I did not reset my image, or perform any other system tasks on it, except running windows update, and the activation message disappeared after some time. If other users can confirm this behavior I would not perform a reset.