# Is there anyway I can preserve installed programs after Windows 'refresh'?

Tags: windows-8.1, reinstall, installer

I am planning on 'refreshing Windows', where Windows will reinstall itself whilst preserving 'personal files' on Windows 8.1 (downloaded as update from Windows store). However, I researched a bit online and apparently it doesn't preserve any installed programs other than Metro apps. Because of this fact, I have tried to collect up all of my installers for the programs I want to keep (I realised how much junk I have on my pc ;) ), but there are some I cannot find and I would rather not have to download them on account of a prohibitively slow internet conenction.

Is there anyway I can keep them or find the instalers?

I realise this is more of two questions but I would like to know if a) there is a folder somewhere with installers (much like every program including an uninstaller); and b) could I just copy the whole folder where the program is installed then re-paste it after the reinstall? It would be the same computer but I feel like this wouldn't work (registry keys - is that relevant?)

Thank you for the help

Comment: No, you cannot keep the apps. if you could, there would be no value in refreshing windows at all. a) no. b) maybe, but probably not for most modern apps. Many will work, Many will not, for exactly the reason you have identified (non-app resources like registery info).

Answer (score 1):

This time you must reinstall all tools with the installers.

After you installed all programs you want to keep, open a [cmd as admin](https://superuser.com/a/497256/174557) and run this [recimg](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/b8/archive/2012/01/04/refresh-and-reset-your-pc.aspx) command:

```
recimg -CreateImage C:\RefreshImage
```

This captures a snapshot of your Windows and includes all desktop programs, too and registered the Image as source for the refresh. The next time you do a refresh, the recimg image is used and all desktop applications are restored.