# INTERNAL POWER ERROR bsod

Tags: windows-8, bsod

I get this error on windows 8. I believe the error is occurring on start up and/ or shut down. In WinDbg I get the following error

```
INTERNAL_POWER_ERROR (a0)
The power policy manager experienced a fatal error.
```

with the following 4 arguments

```
Arguments:
Arg1: 000000000000010a, The disk subsystem failed to properly read or write part of the     hibernation
file.
Arg2: 000000000000000a
Arg3: fffffa8008c01e60, POP_HIBER_CONTEXT
Arg4: ffffffffc0000001, NTSTATUS failure code
```

I was looking for drivers etc to upldate, but the only information I am given which I thought would be useful...

```
MODULE_NAME: nt
IMAGE_NAME:  ntkrnlmp.exe
```

I have a feeling it is my hard drive causing these problems. The BCD on my PC has corrupted twice within 5 months of having it and I have received countless `MEMORY-MANAGEMENT`, `KERNEL SECURITY CHECK FAILURE` and other, kernel related, BSOD. I am un-experienced with debugging BSOD's so I thought I am possibly missing something that a guru on this site may see instantly. I have many `.dmp` files in my minidump folder so I will update my post if I find any incriminating drivers in any older files. Thanks for your help!

**Update 1:** Having looked through more of my dumps, I have a few `PAGE_FAULT_IN_NONPAGED_AREA` BSOD's but 80% of the dump files are `INTERNAL POWER ERROR`. I have also read this could be a thermal error but I am doubtful of this. Also, I have just disabled the hibernate file. After restarting my PC, I didn't have a 'your pc ran into a problem' error like usual but that may have been coincidence.

**Update 2:** Having followed up the comment, I now know which drivers were loaded. I don't believe that you need the full list, but two were highlighted red so I pressume they have importance. The two in question are:

```
ntoskrnl.exe
swenum.sys
```

The swenum.sys I believe is an error regarding Plug and Play, but it is different drivers every time. (Swenum.sys, ksthunk.sys, raspptp.sys, ntoskrnl.exe, crashdmp.sys just to name a few. I found the last particularly interesting as it looked to my untrained eye as though it crashed upon crashing... if that's possible?!)

Comment: The first step.  Use BlueScrenViewer to determine which drivers were loaded when this BSOD happen.  Once you do that update the question with that information.

Comment: @Ramhound I've done this!

Comment: Does this problem happen in a minimal start-up configuration?  Is this a laptop?

Comment: @Ramhound it is not a laptop. I will do a monomial startup now

Comment: @Ramhound I booted minimally twice and no problems occurred so I presume I can now (thankfully) rule out hardware and windows files?

Comment: run **PowerCfg.exe /HIBERNATE /SIZE 100** from a cmd, started as admin (http://superuser.com/a/497256/174557). Dies this fix it?

Comment: @magicandre1981 I have done this but I will have to wait to see if it has fixed my issue

Comment: is it fixed now?