# Corrupted system file CNBJ2530.DPB in Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8.1

My CNBJ2530.DPB system file is corrupted. What are my options for repairing my Windows installation? Is there a way I can replace or repair just this file? I don't have an alternative Windows 8.1 source at home.

Answer (score 2):

This is a known issue under Windows 8 and Windows 8.1 which I reported to Microsoft some time ago. They investigated it, found it internally but have no idea what causes it.

To fix the issue, [open a command prompt as admin](https://superuser.com/a/497256/174557) and run the following [DISM command](http://blogs.technet.com/b/joscon/archive/2012/09/26/fixing-component-store-corruption-in-windows-8-and-windows-server-2012.aspx):

```
DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth
```

This command downloads proper files from Microsoft servers and replaces the corrupted file on the disk with a good file.