# How do I get the icons back on the taskbar in windows 8.1?

Tags: windows-8.1, taskbar, icons

I had a programme on my taskbar and it had an icon.  Sometime later I changed the executable and/or moved it, but now the icon is gone from the taskbar.  The application still runs.  If I unpin it and execute the programme, it does show the correct icon on the taskbar:

[image: unpinned]

But as soon as I pin it, I get this:

[image: pinned]

So it looks like it's trying to get the icon from a place that doesn't exist.  Ideas as to how to refresh this icon?

Comment: try to clear/reset the icon cache: http://www.thewindowsclub.com/rebuild-the-icon-cache-windows

Comment: I would go to the .exe of the program and pin it from there. And if you care to get the correct icon, reset the icon cache as magicandre says.

Comment: @magicandre1981, that worked.  Post it as an answer and I'll mark it as such.

Comment: Still don't know why ppl are down voting my question.  Fly by fruiting!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the Icon Cache is broken. [You have to repair it](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/rebuild-the-icon-cache-windows).

- [open a cmd.exe as admin](https://superuser.com/a/497256/174557)
- close Explorer with Taskmgr
- run those commands from the cmd.exe:

  cd /d %userprofile%\AppData\Local

  attrib –h IconCache.db

  del IconCache.db

  start explorer

Answer (score 0):

How did you run the program the first time? Instead of pinning it after it's running, pin it before it's running by right-clicking the shortcut or executable.

I think this is due to the fact  that lots of shortcuts or executables simply start up another application (like a launcher). So when you pin the actual application, for some reason, Windows can't find the referenced icon.

I'm sure somebody else can elaborate on this!