# Unset "Windows to go" on Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8.1, window, windows-to-go

While trying to boot my Windows 8.1 OS I was able to make it seen as a Windows to Go OS, while now I moved back the HD internally.

In order to enable BitLocker I need to remove the "Windows to Go" setting from the OS, however I didn't find any way to do it from the UI.

**Does anyone know how to revert the "Windows to Go" flag in Windows 8.1?**

Comment: [Only thing I could find on the subject](http://reboot.pro/topic/10534-converting-usb-removable-to-fixed-disk-bcdedit-menu-list/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run this command from a [cmd prompt with admin rights](https://superuser.com/a/497256/174557):

```
reg add HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control /v PortableOperatingSystem /t REG_DWORD /d 0
```

[The value PortableOperatingSystem is the flag you want to change](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2778881). If it is 1, Windows Thinks it is a WindowsToGo.

Comment: That was the setting! Thank you, worked like a charm.

Comment: @magicandre1981 - Would/ could the reverse be true as well? Can a regular Windows be flipped by simply that one flag.. to make it WTG?

Comment: @AlexS I never tried it