# Win 8.1 High non-paged pool RAM usage

Tags: windows-8.1, memory, pagefile

On a spectre x360 laptop w 8GB of RAM running win 8.1, i noticed stuff getting really sluggish.
In task Maanger I could see I was using an obscene amount of RAM (7GB/8GB) but perusing details and soring by Memory desc did not reveal culprit.

After some internet-ing I found that a common issue was non-paged pool size being large where the root cause is possibly a driver memory leak. sure enough, my non-page pool size was 3.2 GB even after restarting.

Under task manager->details, I tried to sort by NP Pool column, but the highest item had only 200k.

At a loss, I decided to try out a much touted solution: the registry modification of clearing the page file at shutdown. open regedit and

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Memory Management
```

look for ClearPageFileAtShutDown and set to 1.

After i did this, I rebooted and viola, RAM at idle down to ~2GB.

Can anyone help explain why this works?
Is there a way I can troubleshoot what the original issue was so that I can set this back to 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, start with [poolmon](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ntdebugging/archive/2012/08/30/troubleshooting-pool-leaks-part-2-poolmon.aspx) to see which driver is causing the high usage.

Install the [Windows WDK](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?linkid=393659), run poolmon (`"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Tools\x64\poolmon.exe"`), sort it via <kbd>P</kbd> after pool type so that non paged is on top and via <kbd>B</kbd> after bytes to see the tag which uses most memory.

Now look which pooltag uses most memory as shown here:

[image]

Now open a cmd prompt, go to C:\Windows\System32\Drivers (`cd C:\Windows\System32\Drivers`) and run the `findstr` command to see which driver uses this tag:

[image]

Now look at the file properties, find the driver version and look for an update.

If the pooltag only shows Windows drivers or is listed in the pooltag.txt (`"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Debuggers\x64\triage\pooltag.txt"`)

you have use [xperf to trace what causes the usage](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-48-WPT-Memory-Analysis-Pool). Install the [WPT from the Windows SDK](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/4847.install-the-windows-performance-toolkit-wpt.aspx), open a [cmd.exe as admin](https://superuser.com/a/497256) and run this:

> xperf -on PROC_THREAD+LOADER+POOL -stackwalk
>   PoolAlloc+PoolFree+PoolAllocSession+PoolFreeSession -BufferSize 2048
>   -MaxFile 1024 -FileMode Circular && timeout -1 && xperf -d C:\pool.etl

capture 30 -60s of the grow. Open the ETL with WPA.exe, add the Pool graphs to the analysis pane.

Put the pooltag column at first place and add the stack column. Now [load the symbols](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/311503/en-us) inside WPA.exe and expand the stack of the tag that you saw in poolmon.

[image]

Now find other 3rd party drivers which you can see in the stack. Here the `Thre` tag (Thread) is used by AVKCl.exe from G-Data. Look for driver/program updates to fix it.

Comment: Wow thanks for the very comprehensive answer. Next time I see this happening I will check this out. Not sure if you happened to see the other part of the question, Is there a basic explanation for why clearing the page file at shut down would resolve the issue?

Comment: I see no relation between both. run the xperf command and look at the stacks.