# High non-paged pool with no stack specified

Tags: memory, performance, debug

So, I followed a guide https://superuser.com/a/988819/662442 to trace a non-paged leak of 4Gb of RAM. In vain. After loading symbolds, no stack is shown for my tag. I can't find any clue as to what to do next.

[image: WPA]

[image: taskmgr]

Comment: any update on the issue?

Answer (score 0):

This means that the allocations were done outside of the trace. Do a rightclick on the columns in WPA and add the `Type` and move AIFO (allocated in trace but not freed inside the trace) to the front as you can see in my picture:

[image]

Those allocations will show a stack.