# Windows 10 high memory usage by tag "File"

Tags: memory, drivers, windows-10, memory-leaks

In trying to determine what was causing the 'system' process to use up a large amount of RAM (which I found very unusual prior to updating to win10), I came across the post here: [Windows 10 high memory usage (unknown reason)](https://superuser.com/questions/949244/windows-10-high-memory-usage-unknown-reason)

Following those instructions, poolmon gives the following output:
[image]

This is problematic, as most drivers seem to use `File` - the output from  `findstr /s File *.sys` has many entries.

I believe the second tag, `wcdl`, is tied to Intel's RST, which may or may not be contributing to the problem.

What can I do to further investigate / solve the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A high "File" usage indicates that programs do a lot of FileIO operations. You have use [xperf to trace what causes the usage](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-48-WPT-Memory-Analysis-Pool). Install the [Windows Performance Toolkit from the Windows 10 SDK](https://dev.windows.com/en-us/downloads/windows-10-sdk), open a [cmd.exe as admin](https://superuser.com/a/497256) and run this:

> xperf -on PROC_THREAD+LOADER+POOL -stackwalk
>   PoolAlloc+PoolFree+PoolAllocSession+PoolFreeSession -BufferSize 2048
>   -MaxFile 2048 -FileMode Circular && timeout -1 && xperf -d C:\poolusage.etl

capture 2-3 minutes of the pool memory usage grow. Open the ETL with WPA.exe, add the Pool graphs to the analysis pane.

Order the columns as you see them in the picture, [load the symbols](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/311503/en-us) inside WPA.exe and expand the stack of the "File" tag that you saw in poolmon.

[image]

Here the `File` tag is used by [locate32.exe](http://locate32.cogit.net/) which scans the file system to build in search index.

*If you still need help, share the compresssed (7z/RAR) ETL file on OneDrive and post the link here in a comment.*

Comment: Great help, thanks, seems to have been mostly due to FoxitReader in my case

Comment: To clarify: A "File" object represents the fact that a file (or a device) has been opened for access (it does not represent a read or a write operation to a file). The poolmon display here shows that almost a million file objects exist at one time. (Not necessarily that many _files_ - a file can be opened several times at once, and a file object would exist for each.) This is likely indicates some truly sloppy programming by someone. It is usually possible to associate such usage with a process by adding the "Handles" column to Task Manager or Process Explorer's processes details display.