# I'm having DNS problems, but can still ping 1.1.1.1: How do I still search the Stack Exchange network?

Tags: linux, windows, dns

I'm having name server resolution problems on one of my machines in my network, but I can still ping 1.1.1.1 and I get a reply, so there is no Internet problem, just a DNS problem.

*Can I still search the Stack Exchange network to look for solutions to my problem **from the machine I'm having the problem on?***

<sub>(Because I can't copy-paste from the machine that works to the machine that doesn't work)</sub>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Yes, you can!  :-)

#### On *nix:

- Open a terminal and type:

  ```
  sudo vi /etc/hosts
  ```
- Navigate to the bottom of the file and press <kbd>i</kbd>

#### On Windows:

- [open a command prompt as admin](https://superuser.com/questions/497252/how-to-access-the-administrator-command-prompt-in-windows-8) and type:

  ```
  notepad C:\Windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts
  ```

#### For both *nix and Windows:

Add the following entries to the bottom of the file:

```
151.101.1.69    askubuntu.com
198.252.206.29  chat.stackexchange.com
151.101.1.69    linux.stackexchange.com
198.252.206.16  sstatic.net
185.53.179.7    stackexchange.com
151.101.65.69   stackoverflow.com
151.101.193.69  superuser.com
172.217.22.14   www.google.com
```

(The above are in alphabetical order, but they don't need to be...)

#### On *nix:

- Hit <kbd>Esc</kbd><kbd>:</kbd><kbd>w</kbd><kbd>q</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

#### In Windows:

- Close Notepad
- Click <kbd>Yes</kbd> when Notepad asks you to save the file

**Done!** You can use now use google to search and read the questions and answer you so desperately need on the Stack Exchange Network.

#### Warning:

Once DNS starts working again, take those entries out of your `hosts` file or you'll run into problems when the SE Engineers will perform their next DR Test...

**Tip:** Save this page off-line so you already have it when you need it most. **:-)**

<sub><sup>**Pro Tip:** Add the above entries to your `hosts` file already *right now* and precede every line with `#` and remove the `#` when you need this solution. 

***No! Don't add them without preceding them with `#` in the unlikely case you might run into DNS problems as most of the above servers have multiple IP addresses assigned and load balancing on the SE network will stop working!*** This is a pro tip: don't do it if you don't know what the implications are! **:-(** Use the normal tip instead!</sup></sub>

Comment: And several weeks later you'll have _more_ problems, when the sites' actual IP addresses change and you've forgotten to remove the static entries.

Comment: @grawity: Answer updated!  Thanks for the tip!

Comment: @Ramhound I'm not talking about changing DNS providers: I'm talking about having DNS problems related to the configuration of the machine...  Neither ISP, Cloudflare nor Google were working: what do you do then? (it was *like* UDP Port 53 being blocked)